# Annoying query error

Tags: php, mysql

Note: I know MySQL is not ideal, but it's already done.

Note: I understand *commited* is incorrectly spelled.

```
QUERY ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, cost, price, count, commited, ordered, cat, subcat, notes, rev_identifier,' at line 1
Query was INSERT INTO stock (name, desc, cost, price, count, commited, ordered, cat, subcat, notes, rev_identifier, sources, totalused, amountfailed) VALUES ('name', 'desc', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'Apple', 'DEV', 'none', '1', 'none', '0', '0')
```

Query is written:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO stock (name, desc, cost, price, count, commited, ordered, cat, subcat, notes, rev_identifier, sources, totalused, amountfailed) VALUES
('$name', '$desc', '$cost', '$price', '$count', '$commited', '$ordered', '$cat', '$subcat', '$notes', '$rev_identifier', '$sources', '$totalused', '$amountfailed')");
```

The $'s are...

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['desc']));
$cost = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['cost']));
$price = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['price']));
$count = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['count']));
$commited = 0;
$ordered = 0;
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['cat']));
$subcat = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['subcat']));
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['notes']));
$rev_identifier = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['rev_identifier']));
$sources = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['sources']));
$totalused = 0;
$amountfailed = 0;
```

Comment: "desc" is a reserved word. Quote it in `reverse quotes`.

Comment: mysql isn't dead. the `mysql_*()` functions for PHP **ARE** deprecated. but the mysql server is still well and alive.

Comment: Why are you calling `strip_tags`?  Are you actually concerned that you're going to get HTML tags posted?  Or are you just using some code that you saw somewhere and figured it was a good idea?  To be clear: You should not need `strip_tags`.

Comment: Thanks, Although mysql functions still work. So really there should be no issues using it in a local not intranet environment?

Comment: @ andy, I always use them, Otherwise couldn't the output not have an iframe in? still i know local system but good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `count`, `desc` column name, it is reserved word so use backtick (“`”)`  to wrap that column names

like

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO stock (name, `desc`, cost, price, `count`, commited, ordered, cat, subcat, notes, rev_identifier, sources, totalused, amountfailed) VALUES
    ('$name', '$desc', '$cost', '$price', '$count', '$commited', '$ordered', '$cat', '$subcat', '$notes', '$rev_identifier', '$sources', '$totalused', '$amountfailed')");
```

Answer (score 2):

`count` is a reserved word in SQL, and you have a column called `count`.  You'll need to put the column name in `backticks` or, better yet, rename the column.

Comment: Renamed the columns with a prefix, Thanks for fix suggestion as well as explaining why it didn't work too!